# Remove git commit

Tags: git

I am having trouble to find a proper solution to my problem: I am writing some code for a project. Every week I get some new features I have to implement and it turned out a certain feature I've already added a month ago can be dropped and removed from the code basis. I know exactly which commit is responsible for that. Is there a command in git to drop that specific commit but leaving the adjustments to the code I have made in the commits afterwards unchanged?

All the best,
David

Comment: It's called a rebase. Please do some research first before asking this.

Comment: It's probably best to remove the code and add a new commit. This keeps a semi-linear history of what happened that you can easily trace, and also allows you to get the code back if necessary.

Comment: Hey @DaveZych, is there an automated way to remove only the changes made by that specific commit from my current head so that I can make such a new commit right away or do I have to look up the code with git-diff and remove it then manually before I can commit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways.

`git rebase -i 'commit to be dropped'`

requires a `git push -f` if the commit is already at server.

This will entirely remove the commit from historic, may be dangerous if your repository is shared, or even forbidden by the server. I recommend you to never do this if the commit is already pushed.

Or you may use

`git revert 'commit to be reverted'`

This will create a new commit that undo your modifications.

Comment: Yeah, git revert is the command I was looking for! Thanks for the help :)